# What is causing the word 'NORMAL' stamped in the top corner of most applications

Tags: linux, x11, nvidia, graphics

There is a word rendered in the top corner of most application I want to get rid of, but I'm not sure what is causing it.

I'm running PopOS 19.04 (based on Ubuntu) with an NVidia GPU and driver (v440 on xServer)

In the top right-hand corner of most application I run there is the word 'NORMAL' It's rendered in a way that shows its not part of the applications and as it's in multiple unrelated applications make me think its graphically related, but I can't find out what is making it appear -- NVidia X server settings doesn't seem to have options that would do this.

It renders under the cursor, and it's in the top corner of the application window rather than the monitor; if I move the application around the screen, the word also moves with it.

Unreal Editor

[image: Unreal Editor]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Discord

[image: Discord]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Nvidia drivers then turn off "Enable G-SYNC/G-SYNC Compatiblle Visual Indicator"

1. Open Nvidia X Server Settings
2. Scroll to OpenGL setting
3. Uncheck Enable G-SYNC/G-SYNC Compatiblle Visual Indicator
4. Save and close/reopen troubled applications